# Regex working when embedded in CSHTML page but not when moved to an external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, razor

*Disclaimer. I've eliminated the possibility of wrong linkage, incorrect regex etc. already. This particular issue isn't a duplicate to those questions. Please, kindly take a minute to read it whole before jumping to premature dupe flags. It's really something else than those basic issues. Please give me some credit for the hours spent googling it. Thanks.*

I noticed that I inherited a lot of pages with embedded explicit JavaScript, so I decided to clean it up and move the script to external files. When I'm done, most of things seems to be working except for a single thing and that's regular expressions. In fact, the weird part is that some of them still work as expected while others fail.

So when I have the following set up directly in the page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Account.js" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
  function isEmailValid(){
    return emailRegex.test($("#email").val());
  }
});
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div>
...
</div>
}
```

everything works fine but when I switch to an external file, it fails ang produces no matches!

I've made sure that the file is correclty linked and that the methods are executed. I know that for sure because the rest of the effects (like *onmouseover* etc.) do work still. And all validation works perfectly too. At first I thought there was something wrong with using regular expressions in the external files (even if it sounds insane) but then I noticed that regex works for most of the cases (which is even more insane).

After a few hours, I'm about to give up and move the stuff back to the CSHTML files, even if it's just plain wrong and ugly...

Comment: Not sure if it's basic or not but I can see double @-characters there. In Razor it's an escape character and it needs to be treated in a different way (double instances, like above). In a pure JS file, there's no need for it. Try matching email addresses like this: *blopp@@dopp.pop*.

Comment: Check the resulting JS, you should see `var emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;`.

Comment: Why do you only allow top domains with between two and six letters?

Comment: @Andreas I noticed that too. Probably, he had *{2,3}* and tried relaxing it while trouble-shooting. To be honest, most top domains will fit withing six characters, so there's a point to it. What's your take on it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes most will fit but there are domains with 20+ letters

Comment: And `co.uk` will not work as it's a-z{2-6},, that does not include dot does it?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't even think about that! In fact, when I design validators for email, I follow very much the setup of OP. Possibly an issue to improve in the future. On the other hand, I've never had a single complaint from any if my **registered and validated** users about that, so it can't be that important... (Yes, the last part is a joke.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten :-) , I think the best way to validate the top domain is to check against the complete list. https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt , so maybe to the right of @ explode on ".", then after that, I'm not sure. The link above does not list `co.uk` for example but `co` and `uk` as two seperate items. But it would probably be needed to get a (real) working way to check agains top domains and not just as OP (and most others do).

Answer (score 3):

You have used escape syntax for @-character on the Razor page (where it's necessary due to the special meaning of it). When the page renders, the sequence *@@* gets translated to *@* and the resulting **actual** regex string that is emitted to the client follows the patter for an email address.

When you moved out the JS (which indeed is a great idea, kudos for that!), the rendition doesn't take place anymore as the file's simply jacked in as-is prior to (or post, depending on where one puts it) creating of the page.

In a pure JS file, there's no need for it. At the current state, you'd match strings like this one: *blopp@@dopp.pop*.

```
$(function(){
  var emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
  function isEmailValid(){
    return emailRegex.test($("#email").val());
  }
});
```

For more info on those and other tricks see e.g. [Ode To Code](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/09/ten-tricks-for-razor-views.aspx).